# How to ask user that my app will collect some data about his usage?

Tags: android, permissions, dialog, user-permissions

I want when the user start the app for the first time, a dialog appears to tell the user that the application will collect some data about his/her usage, and if he/she press accept, the main activity starts, and never ask the user again.

Comment: use premissions https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview

Answer (score 0):

let's break your problem to smaller ones. You will need to activities: MainActivity and PermissionsActivity (add a button with id 'yes' and a button with id 'no'.

A) Launch an activity just one time. We will do so using SharedPreferences and storing a boolean which, if true, means that the dialogue had been previously shown and, otherwise, that it has not been shown.

```
// In MainActivity.class

String MY_PREFS_NAME = "my_prefs"; // can be changed, but it must be done so everywhere
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
Boolean bool = prefs.getBoolean("hasbeenshown", false); 
if (!bool){
    // Go to the request dialogue activity
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PermissionsActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
// otherwise, if bool = true, activity has been shown and there is no need to redirect
```

B) If the user answers, redirect to MainActivity and store the answer.

```
// In PermissionsActivity.class

String MY_PREFS_NAME = "my_prefs"; // can be changed, but it must be done so everywhere
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
Button yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do stuff when they accept
        // ...

        // Store the answer
        store(true); // true means that user said yes
    }
 });

Button no = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
no.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do stuff when they !accept
        // ...

        // Store the answer
        store(false); // false means that user said no
    }
});

void store(Boolean answer){
    // Store the answer
    editor.putBoolean("answer", answer);

    // Don't show the message again
    editor.putBoolean("hasbeenshown", true);

    // Store the previous edits
    editor.commit();

    // Redirect to MainActivity
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(PermissionsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

C) APPENDIX: You can always get what the user answered from any activity with the following code.

```
String MY_PREFS_NAME = "my_prefs"; // can be changed, but it must be done so everywhere
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
Boolean yesorno = prefs.getBoolean("answer", false);  // false will be returned if user didn't answer or answered no; true will be returned if user answered yes
```